# How to show only the days in current month - ionic2-calendar

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native, ionic2-calendar

I'm developing a calendar app using ionic and I want to **show only the current days in the month** in the view. I'm using ionic2-calendar and now it shows the previous month's last days, current month's days, and next month's first days in one calendar view. Please help me with this.

[image]

Comment: You can inspect see which class is getting added to greyed out then based on that class add display:none or visibility:hidden

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!  Finally able to sol ved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Indraraj26 's comment, I finally managed to solve the issue by adding visibility: hidden to the related class in global.scss file . (as below)

```
td.text-muted{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option I can find is to begin the month on the 1st, hiding the greyed out days before the 1st day of the month. Do this by adding the option `[startingDayMonth]=1` to the `calendar` directive, e.g.

```
<calendar
  ...
  [startingDayMonth]=1
  ...
></calendar>
```

As @Indraraj26 pointed out, you could hide `td.text-muted` globally but this could well have side-effects.

I would certainly create an [issue](https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar/issues) to add a similar option for hiding next month's dates.